# Need help in Javascript onChange event

Tags: javascript

On change of a dropdown value, I need to confirm whether the user wants to change the value or changed it by mistake.

If user clicks on OK then system should apply the modification, otherwise the value should not change.

As of now I have written code as follows:

```
document.getElementById("dropdownid").onchange = function (){ 

  var a = confirm("Do you want to change");

  if (a == true){
    return true;
  }

  if (a == false){
    return this;
  }

}
```

here am getting the confirm box but regardless of whether if I press OK or Cancel, the dropdown always shows the new value.

Comment: Show Your .Aspx page If Your are using Dot net

Comment: why are you using `this` ? It will return , just an object, just `return false`, that's it : http://jsfiddle.net/p4n9f/1/

Comment: If user clicks on OK then system should apply the modification?? you want to change the value of the dropdown or any other modification on an other element??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4n9f/4/)

```
var drop = document.getElementById("dropdownid"); 
var selected =drop.options[drop.selectedIndex]; //save selection initially
drop.onclick = function (e){
selected = drop.options[drop.selectedIndex]; // save current selection 
}
drop.onchange = function (e){
var a = confirm("Do you want to change");
if (a == false) // no need to check for true
   {
       selected.selected=true; // if cancel, set the existing selected option
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
document.getElementById("dropdownid").onchange = function (){ 
     var a = confirm("Do you want to change");
    if (a == true)
       {
         return true;
       }
    if (a == false)
       {
         return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: can you please tell me in details, about html code, are you using any other js-function for applying these changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can undo the selection like this:

```
document.getElementById("dropdownid").onchange = function (){
    if (!confirm("Do you want to change")) {
        if (typeof this.prevVal=='undefined') {
            this.prevVal=this.options[0].value;
            for (var i=0;i<this.options.length;i++)
                if (this.options[i].defaultSelected)
                    this.prevVal=this.options[i].value;
        }
        this.value=this.prevVal;
    } else {
        this.prevVal=this.value;
    }
}
```

Basically you save in an attribute the previously selected value, and you search for the default value if not changed yet.

Answer (score -1):

try using this code

```
document.getElementById("dropdownid").onchange = function (eve){ 
   var a = confirm("Do you want to change");
   if (a == true){
     return true;
   }
   if (a == false){
       eve.preventDefault();
   }
}
```